# ASP.NET Core Web API - 'IRuleBuilderInitial<CustomerTransactionRequestDto, decimal>' does not contain a definition for 'CustomCurrency'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

Validation is done in ASP.NET Core-6 Web API using Fluent Validation. So, I have this code:

Custom Validator:

```
public static IRuleBuilder<T, string> CustomCurrency<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
{
    var options = ruleBuilder
        .Matches(@"^\d+.\d{1,2}$")
        .WithMessage("Appropriate Currency format should be xxxxxxxxxxx.xx");

    return options;
}
```

DTO:

```
public class CustomerTransactionRequestDto
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Then the validator:

```
public class CustomerTransactionRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<CustomerTransactionRequestDto>
{
    public CustomerTransactionRequestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(p => p.Amount).CustomCurrency()
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Amount should be not empty. ERROR!");
    }
}
```

The problem is that I got this error:

> Error CS1929  'IRuleBuilderInitial<CustomerTransactionRequestDto, decimal>' does not contain a definition for 'CustomCurrency' and the best extension method overload 'AuthValidatorSettings.CustomCurrency(IRuleBuilder<CustomerTransactionRequestDto, string>)' requires a receiver of type 'IRuleBuilder<CustomerTransactionRequestDto, string>'

Then it highlights:

> RuleFor(p => p.Amount)

How do I get this sorted out?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error message hints that types don't match. You have a custom validator based on `IRuleBuilder<T, string>` while you are trying to chain it to `IRuleBuilderInitial<CustomerTransactionRequestDto, decimal>`. You have a custom validator based on `string` property, while on the other end a `decimal` property.

To fix this, change the type of *Amount* property from `decimal` to `string`:

```cs
public class CustomerTransactionRequestDto
{
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}
```

That way, you can use the validators you already defined in `CustomCurrency()` like `Matches()` which are available for `string` properties.

If `decimal` property is not a mistake, then I'd suggest adding support for `decimal` in `CustomCurrency()` custom validator, like this:

```cs
public static IRuleBuilder<T, decimal> CustomCurrency<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, decimal> ruleBuilder)
{
    // TODO: Your validation.
}
```